# MySQLdb Error Handling in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

Im pretty new to Python and have an SQL Insert statement that throws an exception due a to primary key violation:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Y31 ROB' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

How do you handle this error, so if it is thrown it exits the function?

I have tried:

```
try:
    webcur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES bar")
except (MySQLdb.Error):
    return
```

and also:

```
except (MySQLdb.IntegrityError)
```

but neither seem to work.

Comment: That got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning it to a variable like so:

```
try:
    webcur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES bar")
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    return
```